# Reading various (non-.shp) vector types using ogrinfo

Tags: ogr, osgeo4w, ogrinfo

I am using the OSGeo4W shell to call *ogrinfo* on a directory (geodata) to see what vector files it includes:

[image]

As you see, it lists two shapefiles and it tells me that it is using the shapefile driver; I assume that is the default driver.

However, my folder includes a KML and a GeoJSON as well.

How would I go about including vector files other than shapefiles in the output as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ogrinfo is meant to be used on single datasets. GDAL's Shapefile driver "*treats a whole directory of shapefiles as a dataset, and a single shapefile within that directory as a layer*" but that really is a shapefile speciality. If you want show the ogrinfo output for multiple files, maybe including subdirectories, you will have to use a small tool/script to loop through them one by one.

Answer (score 5):

Directory of shapefiles is a special case for GDAL/OGR and it behaves like a datastore with many layers as you have noticed. As far as I know no other driver has similar behavior. You can test all files in the directory on Windows as

```
for %1 in (*.*) do ogrinfo %1 >>total_ogrinfo.txt
```

The total_ogrinfo.txt file may contain lots of messages like

```
FAILURE: Unable to open datasource `foo.doc' with the following
drivers.
-> netCDF 
...
```